# Linux host specifications

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

This is a general good-to-know query not directly related to programming.
I have been asked to find a linux host which is exactly same in specifications to our current production host.
What excatly does 'same' specification mean?
What are the parameters/factors i should equate(if possible,with commands on how to dig that up in linux).
I make know quite a few of them - but would not harm to consolidate at a place.

Comment: What is the specification of your current production host?

Comment: Thats exactly the question  - what do we mean when we specify 'specification' of a host.What all would it include?

Comment: How should we know? It is **your** production host.

Answer (score 0):

**Exactly same in specifications** means that the linux host should have the same environment that is **relevant** to the system you're hosting in your production environment.

What is **relevant** depends on the system. For example if you're testing a security system, then both environments must have the same users configured and the same firewall configuration (and all other variables affecting security). But if you're testing a system that performs heavy graphics manipulation, probably the firewall is not relevant, so this might be allowed to have a different configuration, but you would need to have the same processor and memory.

So in essence, it means that you must use your best judgement to decide what **'same specifications'** means for your particular use.

Comment: assuming a normal vanilla environment - based on the response,we do have processor,memory,user permission(though thats not exactly a host attribute).What else should i be comparing?